# Why i can't Fetch Data from Mongo DB and Show it to React using Node JS?

Tags: react-native

When I execute the code of my React Native project, I expect to display the data of the claim on the claim page according to the processed ID. However, I keep encountering an error regarding the response. In fact, the request successfully reaches the server, but there seems to be an issue with the response.

```
import axios from "axios";
// Vos importations d'images

export default function CardReclam(props) {
  const { id } = props;
  const [reclamData, setReclamData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/rec/id/6530f7d04c89475b8f97f8ca`);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Réponse avec erreur: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setReclamData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          "Erreur lors de la récupération des données de réclamation:",
          error.message
        );
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <View>
      {reclamData && (
        <View style={styles.card}>
          {/* Utilisez les valeurs de reclamData dans votre interface utilisateur */}
          <View style={styles.dir}>
            <Image source={userImage} style={styles.image} />
            <Text style={styles.title}> Technicien : </Text>
            <Text style={styles.info}> {reclamData.traiteur}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.dir}>
            <Image source={bankImage} style={styles.image} />
            <Text style={styles.title}> Client : </Text>
            <Text style={styles.info}>{reclamData.client}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.dir}>
            <Image source={localImage} style={styles.image} />
            <Text style={styles.title}> Localisation : </Text>
            <Text style={styles.info}>{reclamData.localisation}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
      {/* Le reste de votre composant CardReclam */}
    </View>
  );
}
```